# Checking range of function argument in python

Tags: python, function, exception, arguments

What to do with functions which are numerically valid, but physically out of range?

The reason, I would like my programm to tell me and stop, if the physically correct range is left.

I thought about using the ValueError exception for this error handling.

Example:

```
def return_approximation(T):
  #return T only if it is inbetween 0 < T < 100
  return T
```

Comment: Raise a custom exception if T is less than zero or more than 100?

Comment: So how can we help?

Comment: What do you mean `by physically out of range` and `numerically valid`. Provide some examples and also be more specific.

Comment: This is the use-case for `assert`-statement

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python has the `assert`-statement for this kind of argument restrictions.

```
def return_approximation(T):
    assert 0 < T < 100, "Argument 'T' out of range"
    return T
```

Comment: The assert statement, with synatx: `assert Expression[, Arguments]` raises the AssertionError if Expression fails and uses the Argument with the AssertionError. The assertions can be switched of using `python -O my_prog.py` after correct setup.

Comment: This approach can potentially lead to skipping the check if Python is not in debug mode, as other showed. I think the 'if ... raise' syntax is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You should raise an exception called ValueError.

```
if 0 < T < 100:
    raise ValueError('T must be in the exclusive range (0,100)')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you mean by `physically`.

Generally speaking, if the out-of-range error is caused by external data, you're supposed to raise an exception; if the error comes from your own data, you may use `assert` to abort the current execution.

Comment: I want to distinguish between function intput that is physically correct (in context of the function) and input that is numerically correct (does not produce an error).

Comment: @marou: Then `assert` as described by @mkiever is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply, restrict the returned value to T if it matches your conditions else `return None`, like so:

```
>>> def f(T):
        return T if 0 < T < 100 else None

>>> f(100)
>>> f(99)
99
>>> f(0)
>>> f(1)
1
```

EDIT: solution with exceptions:

```
>>> def f(T):
        if 0 < T < 100:
            return T
        else:
            raise ValueError


>>> f(100)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#475>", line 1, in <module>
    f(100)
  File "<pyshell#474>", line 5, in f
    raise ValueError
ValueError
>>> f(99)
99
>>> f(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#477>", line 1, in <module>
    f(0)
  File "<pyshell#474>", line 5, in f
    raise ValueError
ValueError
>>> f(1)
1
```

You can even output your own message for more clarity:

```
>>> def f(T):
        if 0 < T < 100:
            return T
        else:
            raise Exception('T is out of Range')

>>> f(100)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#484>", line 1, in <module>
    f(100)
  File "<pyshell#483>", line 5, in f
    raise Exception('T is out of Range')
Exception: T is out of Range
```

Comment: Could you elaborate the use of None in this case. For example expected behaviour of the program.

Comment: *Functions that return None to indicate special meaning are error prone because None and other values (e.g., zero, the empty strings) all evaluate to False in conditional expressions.* Thus, it could be less error prone to document and raise an exception. But in this special case it seems that None will not cause any problems.

Comment: @tarashypka, correct, but that depends on the application, it can be used as a return condition to decide for the next step, I was not clear about OP requirements whether to return something to test with or raise an exception, but I was about to add something on that too.

Comment: @marou, The first function, was returning value of T if it is between 0 and 100, else it will return `None`, the second function, will eventually raise and exception if T is not between 0 and 100.